# What does the second tick mean in Telegram group-chats?

Tags: chat, telegram

Telegrams FAQ only explain what the green ticks mean in a normal chat ( https://telegram.org/faq#q-what-do-the-green-ticks-mean ).

Does anyone know what the second tick in a group-chat **exactly** means?
Does it mean **one** person has read the message? Or **all** people in the group? Or maybe **half** of them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Same as in normal chat. **One person** read message.
>   -- *DrKLO (github.com)*

Source: https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram/issues/397

Comment: Your source is a broken link :(

Answer (score 0):

As long as the tick gets doubled soon and during this short period it's not possible for all of the members to open the chat, I assume that at least one has read the message. But I like the "half" theory :)))))

Answer (score -1):

It means exactly what it says in the FAQ.

One tick - Your message has been sent successfully and is waiting for them to open the app and look at it.

Two ticks - They have opened your message.

Comment: Yeah but what do you mean by "they"? Does it mean at least one person has opened the message or all people in the group?